# Remove unwanted content on client side browser

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

> This will be used for removing unwanted content within my automated
>   selenium scripts!

My question:
Is it possible on the client side to remove unwanted HTML code using JavaScript or some other technology?

Example scenario:

- Facebook timeline defaults to 10 posts at max on screen at any time
- I load facebook and 10 posts are generated [ 2 of these posts are by user 'John' ]
- I run a [JavaScript?] script that will grab all divs where the content is posted by user 'John' and remove them from my browser
- ** 2 new posts are generated automatically -- or not !
     (The requirement is to remove unwanted content (similar to AdBlocker?).. 
     if the site generates 2 new posts, that's a plus!)

I'm not looking for someone to code me a solution to this problem, but instead push me in the right direction (a solution is a bonus!)

I will then update this question (if it lives) with the solution I have come up with and clean up the post !

NOTE: I understand Facebook already has a built in 'stop following' button to cover this.
The scenario could be that if the content includes 'someone you might know!' then I want to remove this section of HTML from my browser !

Update:
Since there's no code, I've added another example scenario!

- I load this  SO question in selenium
- I'm so confident that this post will get voted up rather than down!

HTML currently contains:

> ```
>  <div id="content">
>      <p>
>          <em>prepares for -10 within seconds<em>
>      </p>
>  </div>
> ```

- I run a [JavaScript?] script in the current browser which searches the HTML for 'prepares for -10 within seconds'
- If found, I want to remove the parent section and all of its content

HTML then contains:

> ```
>  <div id="content">
>  </div>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a proxy such as [BrowserMob Proxy](https://bmp.lightbody.net/)... Their landing page reads,

> It can capture performance data for web apps (via the HAR format), as
>   well as **manipulate browser behavior and traffic, such as whitelisting
>   and blacklisting content**, simulating network traffic and latency, and
>   rewriting HTTP requests and responses.

You could use the proxy to filter out those elements you wish to remove.